# Facebook debug returns 403 Forbidden and i can't solve it

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

i've read all the other questions about this subject and so far i can't figure out what's the problem.

The website is http://bowarrow.de and it works fine. Only Facebook has a 403 problem. I added meta tags and i find them in the source code.

Still "Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code." if i enter it here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I contacted my hoster to ask if it is a mod_security error but they said there is no mod_security on my account.

I use hostgator as a host and host europe for my domain.

Comment: Your 403 seems to be resolved now. Please check [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbowarrow.de%2F) details for other warning

Comment: Really? I still get the same error in any browser. weird...

Comment: Strange I am also getting 403 now, was getting 200 earlier!

Comment: could it be a hoster problem?

Comment: Probably, just check with them to be sure

Comment: I will contact them again. Yesterday they couldn't help me.

What's weird is that the debugger finds some information from the website so it has access to it but why is it 403 then.

Comment: Do i need ssl set up for facebook? Because that's what hostgator is saying. But it's not an app, so no, right? They say nothing is blocked.

Comment: By no means do you need to setup ssl just to make sure that your site is accessible to Facebook.

Comment: Ok yeah i thought so. I've tried to access the page through curl with different facebook scraper headers and it works fine (200) even the open graph checker works fine: http://ogp.spypixel.com/Pogo/checker/index.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbowarrow.de%2F

I'm desperate and can't solve the problem.